# Stacked barplot in seaborn using numeric data as hue

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, seaborn, stacked-chart

I have a simple pandas dataframe of 3 columns (month, amount, category) where each row represent an expense of a certain category:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'Month': ['Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar'], 'Amount': [5, 65, 29, 200, 28.5, 12, 4, 100, 21], 'Category': ['Travel', 'Food', 'Dentist', 'Dentist', 'Food', 'Travel', 'Food', 'Sport', 'Sport']}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

I'd like to create a seaborn bar plot where each bar represent the total amount of expenses per month, and each bar is split into different color, where each hue represents the total expense of a particular category on that month.

I was able to achieve the result using a pretty convoluted method and the plotting using matplotlib:

```
df = df.groupby(['Month', 'Category']).sum()   
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
pivot_df = df.pivot(index='Month', columns='Category', values='Amount')
df.plot.bar(stacked=True, colormap='tab20')
```

But this method gives error when trying to use seaborn, and it seems unnecessary complicated.

Is there a better way to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your initial method is complicated because you have unnecessary steps. You `groupby` and `pivot`, but the same aggregation and reshaping can be done at once with `pivot_table`. From your initial DataFrame:

```
df_pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, index='Month', columns='Category', values='Amount', aggfunc='sum')
df_pivot.plot.bar(stacked=True, colormap='tab20')
```

[image]

---

As for using `seaborn`, I wouldn't. They don't really support a stacked barplot, and all of their examples which [*look* like stacked plots](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/part_whole_bars.html) only have two categories where they plot the total, and then overlay one group (giving the impression it's stacked). But this method doesn't easily extend to more than 2 groups.

But if you want that *seaborn feel* you can use their defaults.

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()

df_pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, index='Month', columns='Category', values='Amount', aggfunc='sum')
df_pivot.plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

[image]